# Can't refer the range of selection to any specific sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a macro to print the range of cells and it's content in the console. The macro is doing just fine. However, the problem is I can't use a button (in another sheet) conected to that macro. To be clearer - I created a macro-enabled button in `sheet2` whereas the range of cells I wanaa select and print are within `sheet1`.

I've tried so far:

```
Sub LoopAndPrintSelection()

    Dim ocel As Range, RangeSelected As Range

    Set RangeSelected = Application.Selection

    For Each ocel In RangeSelected.Cells
        Debug.Print ocel.Address, ocel.value
    Next ocel

End Sub
```

***How can I refer the range of selection to any specific sheet?***

Comment: What do you mean by "refer the range of selection to any specific sheet"? Sheet1 must be active for you to select a range on it, so you can't click a button on Sheet2 and maintain that selection. A selection is on the active sheet.

Comment: `Selection` is based on the active sheet, so (and I cannot believe I am saying this) you need to activate Sheet1 before setting the range.

Comment: Sorry @Pᴇʜ. I've taken out my comment.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, the "Application.Selection" property will refer to what you have selected in your active sheet. I would recommend that you assign a hotkey to this macro and then you can select the cells you want to print and use the macro's hotkey.

This is one possible solution, but if you need that button on a different sheet and want people to interact with the button (rather than a hotkey) then this won't solve your issue.

Comment: Another option is to use `Application.InputBox` to allow the user to select the range.

Answer (score 0):

This should help with the issue of two different tabs

```
Sub DUMMY_TEST()

Dim myAREA As Range
Dim mySELECTION As Range

On Error GoTo error_spot

'Stop Excel from "blinking" as tabs are selected/changed and calculating.
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Set mySELECTION = Application.Selection  'Used to get back to same spot after code has executed


If Sheets("Sheet1").Visible = True Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
Else
    'tab not visible, end sub
    GoTo error_spot
End If


Set myAREA = Application.Selection

For Each ocel In myAREA.Cells
        Debug.Print ocel.Address, ocel.Value
    Next ocel


mySELECTION.Worksheet.Activate
mySELECTION.Select

error_spot:

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


End Sub
```